# Can't start js file using nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, window

task.js

```
console.log("Hello world");
```

I tried

```
node task.js
```

and get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

task.js is in the same folder

.load task.js works fine

Comment: Triple backticks to format your code.

Comment: The code with the console.log statement is perfectly fine and runs without any problem. My guess is you have some invisible special character that you accidentally inserted in your task.js file

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` means node has found your file and is attempting to execute it, but it found a character somewhere it doesn't belong.

Answer (score 0):

Everything works in cmd (I was using node.exe before).